# Rails 4: Normal CSS/JS development workflow for asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have an application originally developed in Rails 3 which I've updated to Rails 4. The asset pipeline still confuses me, and in particular, developing CSS and JS is rather painful because whatever changes I've made to `mystyles.css` or `myscripts.js` get overridden by the older versions compiled into `application.css` and `application.js` whenever I issue a `rake assets:precompile`.

I'm sure it's not intended that every time you tweak `mystyles.scss.erb` file (2 seconds in a text editor) and reload the browser (5 seconds) you should need to run `rake assets:clean; rake assets:precompile` (2 minutes, maybe?)

I imagine there's just some part of the upgrade process from Rails 3 to Rails 4 that I missed, or did wrong. I am using the [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets) gem for a few reasons, and I hope it's not caused by that.

Comment: Have you added this in application.rb, `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.png *.jpg *.jpeg )` and 
`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=true`, once you do this, you can directly include stylesheets and js files directly using the stylsheet and javascript helpers.

Comment: I think that doesn't work with Heroku? I've got `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in application.rb, along with a note saying "Prevent initializing application and connecting to the database during precompilation. Heroku requires this to be false." Might it work to put your line in development.rb?

Comment: You can add the lines given above in `application.rb`, I too have hosted few projects with `initialize_on_precompile` set to true, and there had not been a single occasion when I had to do `rake assets:clean`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [the official Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation) says:

> In `config/environments/development.rb`, place the following line:
>
> ```
> config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"
> ```
>
> The `prefix` change makes Sprockets use a different URL for serving assets in development mode, and pass all requests to Sprockets. The prefix is still set to `/assets` in the production environment. Without this change, the application would serve the precompiled assets from `/assets` in development, and you would not see any local changes until you compile assets again.
>
> In practice, this will allow you to precompile locally, have those files in your working tree, and commit those files to source control when needed. Development mode will work as expected.

I have this line *commented out* in my `development.rb`. I'll try re-enabling it and see whether that fixes things...